# Can you create a WDM driver for Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2017 and WDK 10.0.17110.1002

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdm

So I've got Visual Studio 2017 Community and WDK 10.0.17110.1002 installed. I would like to create a WDM device driver for Windows 8.1 Pro. Do I need to install WDK 8.1 with Visual Studio 2012/2013 in order to build a compatible driver for Windows 8.1 or will Visual Studio 2017 with WDK 10 work ?

Comment: I don't know if VS Community is supported, but VS 2017 and WDK 10 can be used to build drivers for Win 7 and later.

Comment: @luke. thanks if you post an answer i will accept it.